# Is this the correct way of splitting a large file?

Tags: c

I need to split a large image or text file into multiple chunks of 10 bytes. These chunks will be sent via UDP to a server. The problem is: 
1. Im unsure about this code. Is this a good way of splitting files? 
2. The programs memory usage is pretty high. 400 KB only for this function.

```
int nChunks = 0;
char chunk[10];
FILE *fileToRead;
fileToRead = fopen(DEFAULT_FILENAME, "rb");

while (fgets(chunk, sizeof(chunk), fileToRead)) {
    char *data = malloc(sizeof(chunk));
    strcpy(data, chunk);

    packet *packet = malloc(sizeof(packet));
    packet->header = malloc(sizeof(packetHeader));
    packet->header->acked = 0;
    packet->header->id = ++nChunks;
    packet->header->last = 0;
    packet->header->timestamp = 0;
    packet->header->windowSize = 10;
    packet->data = data;

    list_append(packages, packet);
}


typedef struct packetHeader{
    ...
}packetHeader;

typedef struct packet{
    packetHeader *header;
    void *data;
}packet;
```

Comment: yup, looks good to me. move the `malloc` outside the `while loop`. reading in bytes from `FILE` stream into a buffer and then reusing the buffer. :)

Comment: 400KB is nothing to worry about - even phones have several GB.

Comment: is it batter to free `header` and `data` after `list_append

Comment: @suspectus several GB of RAM? IBTD.

Comment: Any reason for copying `chunk` into `data` and then into `packet->data` instead of into `packet->data` directly?

Comment: is it batter if you to free `data` and `header` every time after `list_append` function call.?

Comment: I tried with $char data[sizeof(chunk)];$ however all the data in list are duplicates of each other. Only the last string is put into that memory adress.

Comment: @Aean: Most systems will free up the memory when the program terminates. What will cause memory to leak here is the lack of a `fclose` call

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem: You're right, thanks. Withdrawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a good way of splitting files?

When the file consists of ten-character chunks of text, this is OK; since in your case the file is an image, not a text, you should use [`fread`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fread.html) instead of `fgets`.

In addition, you should be passing `sizeof(chunk)`, not `sizeof(chunk)+1` as the size. Otherwise, `fgets` writes an extra byte past the end of the memory space allocated by your program.

Finally, you shouldn't be using `strcpy` to copy general data: use `memcpy` instead. In fact, you can avoid copying altogether if you manage buffers inside the loop, like this:

```
#define CHUNK_SIZE 10
...
// The declaration of chunk is no longer necessary
// char chunk[10];
...
for (;;) {
    char *data = malloc(CHUNK_SIZE);
    size_t len = fread(data, CHUNK_SIZE, 1, fileToRead);
    if (len == 0) {
        free(data);
        break;
    }
    // At this point, the ownership of the "data" can be transferred
    // to packet->data without making an additional copy.
    ...
}
```

> The programs memory usage is pretty high. 400 KB only for this function.

This is because reading a file goes much faster than sending it via UDP. That's why the program manages to read the whole file into memory before the first few UDP packets get sent. You will be better off reading and sending in the same loop, rater than queuing up a whole list of packets upfront. When you read as you send, the slower part of the process controls the overall progress. This would let your program use a tiny portion of the memory space that it uses now, because there would be no buffering.

Comment: fRead() is faster and uses 25KB less. However I get "\276" at the end of some of the chunks. What is that? That number is incremental.

Comment: @WalterWhite `fread` is supposed to give you only what's in the file, no stray data should get there. This may be a problem related to using `strcpy` - if there's zero, `strcpy` stops early, leaving "heap garbage" from `malloc` in place of the actual bytes from your image.